# Show multiple base64 encoded image with Android gallery like they are in one folder

Tags: javascript, android, image, cordova

Using Cordova 3.5 - I have base64 encoded image array. Multiple images. They are in javascript array. Now I can send the base64 image to JAVA and manipulate it. I will be able to open it using **android gallery**.

But is there any way to open multiple images with one command so that next image is visible with swipe, sorted alphabetically ??

I will sent the encoded image array , convert them. I want to open them together **without saving them in storage**. So the user will be able to view the next image with just a swipe. Is it possible?

I searched on net, can't find any solution on opening multiple images together.

Comment: You can do that in HTML using a gallery slider.

Comment: @JamesWong not really. I want to use android gallery. Mainly for zooming functionality. Swipe,zoom all together. Cordova zooming using scaling is crap.That will be last option.